# Java regex to split a string by using different delimiters

Tags: java, regex, split

Suppose I want to split a string by either space character or the `%20` string, how should I write my regex?

I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
String regex = "[\\s+, %20]";
String str1 =  "abc%20xyz";
String str2 = "abc xyz";

str1.split(regex);
str2.split(regex);
```

The regex doesn't seem to work on `str1`.

Answer (score 3):

use the alternation `|`:

```
String regex = "(?:\\s+|%20)+";
```

Comment: Whats' the meaning of `?:`?

Comment: @OneTwoThree: `(?:...)` is for grouping without capturing

Comment: Wait, but this is not the same as what I'd want. (I believe this regex means to split by one or more '%20', which is not what I want.)

Comment: @OneTwoThree: I am not sure what you are looking for, but you have now all the tools to make your own pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
String regex = "(\\s{1}+|%20{1}+)";
```

Comment: In  your `{1}+` is like saying I want exactly one of those characters once or more times?

Comment: No,`{1}+`is like say once times,`++`means once or more times,e.g. `"abc%20%20%20xyz".split("([%20]++)").length==2;` but `"abc%20%20%20xyz".split("(%20+)").length==4;`

Comment: Hmm that is interesting. Thanks for piquing my curiosity, I'll have to read up on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split by ONE space or ONE "%20", try this:

```
String regex = "(\\s|%20)";
```

If you want to split by AT LEAST ONE space or AT LEAST ONE "%20", then try this:

```
String regex = "(\\s+|(%20)+)";
```